# Spring MVC controller - getPathInfo() is null

Tags: spring-mvc, controller

I have worked servlet that need to convert to Spring MVC controller to have access spring beans etc. Why in normal servlet `request.getPathInfo()` return not `null`, but in Spring Controller i get null value ? I know i can use `@PathVariable`, but wonder why the results of this method is the difference?

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/test", "/test/*"})
public void test(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {

    log.info(req.getPathInfo() == null); // true!

    if (req.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("get")) {
        // analogue to doGet...
    } else {
        // analogue to doPost...
    }

}
```

Comment: what is the URL you are hitting?

Comment: URL: `http://localhost:8080/myApp/test/hello`. `req.getPathInfo()` shuld return `/hello`

Answer (score 14):

I think the solution is in the javadoc of getPathInfo()

> The extra path information follows the servlet path but precedes the
>   query string and will start with a "/" character.

In case of Spring the servlet path is the full path hence if you call getServletPath() it will always return the full URI and getPathInfo() will return nothing.

Comment: This should certainly be marked as the correct answer by now.

Comment: This great, Thanks. The thing is, I have this filter used by many different app, some spring boot, others not. So, I need to make a distinction in the filter between the request coming from spring boot or not. Is there a good way to do this other than just checking both getPathInfo() and getServletPath().
Something like this
`
if(null != getPathInfo()){
 path = getPathInfo();
}else{
   path = getServletPath();
}
`